# Duplicate items of a list

Tags: f#

If I want to duplicate the elements in a list how would I go about and do it?
I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
let List = [(1,2);(3,4)]
let v = List.map(fun (x,y) -> List.replicate 2 (x,y)) List
```

I want the result to be [(1,2); (1,2); (3,4); (3,4)]. Any advice would be much appreciated. If possible, I want to do it using only higher order.

Comment: Looking at your example code, the fact that your list items are tuples isn't actually relevant to your question. You just want to duplicate the list items so that `[A; B]` becomes `[A; A; B; B]`. In this case, `A` is `(1,2)` and `B` is `(3,4)`, but they could have been anything and your question would still have the same answer.

Comment: @rmunn Yep, I thought that too. Title adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a list comprehension for readability:

```
let items = [ (1, 2); (3, 4) ]

let duplicated = [
    for item in items do
    yield item
    yield item
]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `List.collect`, which is F#'s implementation of `flatmap` (if you come from a functional background), `SelectMany()` (if you come from C#), or `smooshMap` (if you come from a potential future version of JavaScript).

```
let items = [(1,2); (3,4)]

let result =
    items
    |> List.collect (fun item -> [item; item])
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of good solutions, but I thought I would point out some mistakes in your original code, especially since you are pretty close.

1. Try not to assign module names to variables as it can get confusing: i.e. name your variable `list` not `List`, or `xs`
2. As functions in F# are curried, it is customary to add a space between the function and its parameters (except maybe for .NET related non-curried API calls). So add a space between `List.map` and `(fun x->.... )`
3. If you don't need to deconstruct the tuple, you can just name it as one argument, `x`.
4. Finally, because you `List.map` will result in a list of lists, you can use `List.collect` or `List.concat`

So:

```
let xs = [(1,2);(3,4)]
let v = List.map (fun x -> List.replicate 2 x) xs |> List.concat
```

or

```
xs
|> List.collect (fun x -> List.replicate 2 x)
```

or if you want to get fancy

```
xs |> (List.replicate 2 >> List.concat)
```

Comment: the last version does not work; it'll replicate the whole list twice and not each element